# Unity сохранение в persistentDataPath на Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Подскажите как приложение из Unity может сохранять данные в persistentDataPath на устройстве Android?

1. ставил опцию "external sd card";
2. пробовал сохранять в dataPath;
3. менял / на Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
4. ставил в начале пути "file:///"

Не сохраняет.

Answer (score 0):

1. поставить External (SDCArd).
2. Попробуйте понять как с ним работать на примере ниже.
3. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Дополнительную информацию вы можете почитать тут: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html

```
    private void Start()
    {
        //По желанию можно создать папку и сохранять туда данные
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath+"/Save");

        //путь к папке: storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Имя вашего пакета>/files/Save << Папка
        File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Save/test.txt","Hello World!");
    }
```

Comment: не нахожу папку /storage.